# lambdaからcapture-listを取得する方法

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

c++のlambda式から、キャプチャした変数のリストを取得することはできますか？

```
int x = 10;
auto f = [x](){};
//auto captureList = f.captureList;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

英語版で同様の質問 ([Get captured variables from lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963041/get-captured-variables-from-lambda)) がありました。結論から言うと「できない」ようです。

リンク先で引用している言語仕様 (5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda]) をざっと訳してみると

- コピーキャプチャに対しては、static ではない、無名のデータメンバがクロージャ内で宣言される。その順番は規定しない。
- 参照キャプチャに対しては、そのようなデータメンバを宣言するかどうかも規定しない。

なので、キャプチャについてのメタデータはないと思います。